# -webkit-transform(hover tooltip) not working in Safari (Windows 7) but works in Chrome, Opera, IE 9, and Firefox (all latest)

Tags: css, safari, webkit, tooltip, transform

I've unsuccessfully trying to get a hover to popup a tooltip in Safari in Windows 7.  It works in Chrome, IE 9,  Firefox, and Opera (all latest versions).  I can get the tooltip to popup in Safari if I comment out a few lines of CSS although the 'fade in' effect I want also goes away--but it works. (I have indicated commented out block lines below).  Can anyone help me understand 1. How to fix this? 2. Why two webkit browsers are working differently?

Here is the code (HTML portion first and then CSS portion).

HTML (relevant portion):

```
    <div class="mycontainer">
       <div class="myblock has-tooltip">Content I can hover over<span  class="tooltip">content in tooltip popup</span></div>
    </div>
```

CSS (relevant portion):

```
.has-tooltip {
cursor: help;
font-family: "Gill Sans", Impact, sans-serif; 
font-size: 20px; */
margin: 20px 75px 10px 45px;
padding: 0.5em;
position: relative;
text-transform: uppercase;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* webkit flicker fix */
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* webkit text rendering fix */
```

}

```
.has-tooltip .tooltip {
background: #FF6600;
bottom: 100%;
color: #fff;
font-size: 0.8em;
font-weight:100;
display: block;
left: -1em;
margin-bottom: 0.6em;
opacity: 0;
padding: 1em;
position: absolute;
visibility: hidden;
width: 140%; 

-webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(10px);
   -moz-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(10px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(10px);
     -o-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(10px);
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(10px);
```

/* NOTE: IF I COMMENT THIS BLOCK BELOW OUT THE TOOLTIP SHOWS IN SAFARI TOO */

```
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-out;
   -moz-transition: all 1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease-out;
     -o-transition: all 1s ease-out;
        transition: all 1s ease-out;
```

/* NOTE: IF I COMMENT THIS BLOCK ABOVE OUT THE TOOLTIP SHOWS SAFARI TOO */

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
   -moz-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
    -ms-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
     -o-box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
        box-shadow: 2px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.28);
```

}

```
/* This bridges the gap so you can mouse into the tooltip without it disappearing */
.has-tooltip .tooltip:before {
bottom: -1em;
content: " ";
display: block;
height: 1em;
left: 0;
position: absolute;
width: 100%;
```

}

```
/* CSS Triangles - see Trevor's post */
.has-tooltip .tooltip:after {
border-left: solid transparent 0.5em;
border-right: solid transparent 0.5em;
border-top: solid #FF6600 0.5em;
bottom: -0.5em;
content: " ";
height: 0;
left: 50%;
margin-left: -1em;
position: absolute;
width: 0;
```

}

```
.has-tooltip:hover .tooltip {
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible; 
-webkit-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
   -moz-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
     -o-transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important;
        transform: translateX(0px) translateY(0px) !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code (including the part you indicated) works fine for me in Safari 6.0.2 on Mountain Lion. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCRoT.png

Comment: It's Safari for Windows.  I apologize, I'll fix the heading and question to indicate this.